# Reactor Multiplexing: Dispatch event to just exactly one subscriber

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am playing a bit with Reactor right now. While trying to build a small demo game (just to get accustomed to the framework), I need the ability to have multiple "entities" subscribed to a publisher. But I also need each published event to reach exactly one subscriber. For now, they all always get it. I know that I could build some "latch" into this event so that all but one subscriber discard it.

But I think in the sea of features, there might be an operator or something that already does exactly this...

Multiple subscribers to a single publisher. Each subscriber would need to apply a different filter too though.
Each event from the publisher going only to a single subscriber in no particular order... (The filter does not guarantee uniqueness, there could be multiple subscribers using the same filter).

Randomness is cool but not required (since the subscriber will unsubscribe upon receiving this event). You might have guessed that this will be the kill signal for the entity ;).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [UnicastProcessor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/UnicastProcessor.html) does the trick.